# Displaying a timer in a panel using JLabel

Tags: java, eclipse, timer, jpanel, jlabel

So I am making a program with a fellow classmate and we haven't had much experience with GUI but what I am trying to do is display a timer of how long a user takes to complete a puzzle in a side panel (there's a main game area and a side panel beside it with buttons and such) but I'm not sure how I can get the `JLabel` to constantly update with the time that the user takes to solve the puzzle.
I don't know how I can use a timer object to do this so I've tried to use just `System.nanoTime()` for now.

1) if I am using a timer object, what do I use in the Action listener parameters? Will this call the `timerLabel.updateUI();` each time (assuming I have the actionPerformed method with that line of code in it already)? Using a timer object what will I need to put into the Jlabel param when creating it?

2) if not using the timer object what would be the best way to update the time constantly?

```
//Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(??));
//timer.start();
long start = System.nanoTime();
String time = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("ms").format(new java.util.Date(start/1000000));
timerlabel = new JLabel(time);
sideMenu.add(timerlabel);
timerlabel.updateUI();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand how to use the `ActionListener`. `ActionListener` doesn't take any parameters as it is an interface; instead, you override its `actionPerformed` method. What you might be looking for is this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        // Whatever action you want to happen every 1000 milliseconds
        timerLabel.setText(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("ms")
            .format(new java.util.Date(System.nanoTime()/1000000)));
    }
});
timer.start();
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SwingTimers.htm) for a pretty good example.

Comment: On the .updateText line it says that it is an undefined method for type JLabel, is there any method in JLabel that updates itself like this one?

Comment: Its .setText, so now i got that error out of the way, it doesnt actually seem to update ever, shouldnt it be changing every 1000ms?

Comment: My System.nanoTime was outside the actionPefromed method, solved it, thanks for the help!

Comment: @ShadowBlade Sorry, I meant `setText`, not `updateText`. I'll make that edit. If this answer worked for you, please accept it! Glad I could help you, by the way. :)